# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MYAPP.WebUI._Default'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dll, asp.net-mvc-routing

I keep getting the following error when I run the project in Visual Studio 10. I got this project from someone else, and I have to expand it, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with route values, since it came from an another computer. However I don't know how to do that. It was working before, but then I tried to connect to the database (by creating a new user) and then this started happening.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this     request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MYAPP.WebUI._Default'.
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"   Inherits="MYAPP.WebUI._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <%-- Please do not delete this file. It is used to ensure that ASP.NET MVC is  activated by IIS when a user makes a "/" request to the server. --%>
Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 1
```

The Default.aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
     public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
        // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
        // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

        string originalPath = Request.Path;
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
    }
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. turns out using Chrome web browser, if you log into the mvc app with multiple tabs open, the system gets confused. I started using Internet Explorer, which stops the debugger in Visual Studio automatically preventing this from happening.